# How can I allow incoming SSH (SCP) connections?

Tags: macos, ssh, scp

How can I allow incoming SSH connections on my mac (Mac OS X 10.6.4) from other machines on the same network?
Every time I'm trying to `scp` something on the machine I get a **Connection refused** error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In order to allow SSH incoming connections to your Mac, you need to enable Remote Login in Sharing Preferences pane.

Here’s a picture:
[image: Sharing Pane]